# Oracle: Error launching job through dbms_scheduler

Tags: oracle, jobs

This is the instruction I use:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(25950);
  commit;
END;
```

And this is the error I get

```
ORA-00931: missing identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 132
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 164
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 218
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 437
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Comment: if you're using Toad (or probably other IDEs) you can use autocomplete by typing: exec dbms_scheduler.run_job(    then wait a sec or two after "(" and the param list will show the names and types of the params.  You can also use "desc dbms_scheduler;" even if in SqlPlus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run_job` expects the `job_name`, not an id.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#autoId67):

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB (
   job_name                IN VARCHAR2,
   use_current_session     IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE);
```

Comment: I didn't know the existence of a Job name. From toad I didn't notice that colum. Tomorrow I'll try. Thanks